# Set domain name for raspberry pi?

Tags: networking, wifi

I have set up a communication system for my pi to receive commands from my computer with netcat running on the pi, and processing on the computer to control a robot. My issue is that I have my raspberry pi's IP address in the code on my computer, so if my pi moves to a different network, it will not connect. I want these two devices to connect across networks, so I am assuming that my best option would be to assign my raspberry pi a domain name such as "google.com" so that I can send data from anywhere to anywhere without needing an IP address.
Is it possible to do this?
If not, is there a better way to achieve this solution? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You COULD assign a domain name, if you have one, and want to address it over the internet. You need network services to enable domain name resolution.

What I suspect you actually want is to symbolically address your Pi on a local network.

The Pi, like most Linux systems, has a `hostname`; `raspberrypi` by default.

You can see this by entering `hostname` on the command line.

You can change it to something different (and preferably unique) in `raspi-config`.

Raspbian (you have not told us what you are using), by default, runs `avahi` as a [Zero-conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) client. This enables programs to discover hosts running on a local network.

You can easily connect from Linux and OS X with `ssh pi@hostname.local` (the default hostname is raspberrypi) This should work with popular GUI ssh programs. This is sometimes problematic with some versions of Windows and networks which use .local in a non-standard way. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local)

NOTE `.local` resolution does not work in some contexts e.g. in `rsync`. The following should resolve IP (and can be included in bash scripts)
`RemotePi=$(getent hosts hostname.local | awk '{ print $1 }')`

`.local` resolution does work on some Windows systems, and there may be alternate solutions using the `hostname` on Windows.

Comment: Well butter my spinach, I wasn't aware of the `hostname.local` thing. Much nicer than using local network IP.

Comment: and what if we don't want to use .local.  what if we do want to use an actual xxx.net type domain?